# Replacement for CAPICOM

Tags: .net, cryptography, lotus-notes, lotusscript, capicom

Now CAPICOM is deprecated, and MSDN recommends to use .net classes from System.Security.Cryptography. But I have one Lotus Notes application, which using CAPICOM from LotusScript code (very similar to VisualBasic) for displaying certificates to users, and get some cert info (Subject and ValidToDate fields).

How can I replace CAPICOM functionality with .net or any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Framework has it's X509Certificate class, and if X509Certificate capabilities (which are limited) are insufficient, you can use PKIBlackbox of our SecureBlackbox product, which is available as .NET components.

Update: the ActiveX edition has been discontinued. .NET edition is still available. The text above has been updated accordingly (the accepted answer can't be deleted).

Comment: the link is no longer available

Comment: @Somebody I've updated the answer. The answer can't be deleted.